# React Native Android Native View life cycle events

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-native-router-flux

I am working on the exporting android native view into React Native component. The view has a set of required life cycle methods to be called (onPause, onResume, onDestroy). Since React Native uses only one Activity for the entire application I can not hook these methods to the main activity. 
I tried to use some View events:

```
@Override
  protected void onVisibilityChanged( View changedView, int visibility) {
    super.onVisibilityChanged(changedView, visibility);
    if (visibility == View.VISIBLE) {
      this.startSensors();
    }
    else {
      this.stopSensors();
    }
  }


  @Override
  public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasWindowFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasWindowFocus);
    if (hasWindowFocus) {
      this.startSensors();
    }
    else {
      this.stopSensors();
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    this.startSensors();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
    super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    this.stopSensors();
  }
```

This events however only triggered when I directly change the exported component inside it's parent component, and not triggered when I change the main screen using React Native Navigation (using react-native-router-flux).

I also tried to export the life cycle functions into react NativeUtils and call them within ComponentDidMount and ComponentWillUnmount, but ComponentWillUnmount is not called on change of the scene.

Is there a way to listen to equivalent of onPause(), on Resume(), onDestroy() events for a View, or is there a way to handle this on React Native side?

Comment: Why are you not using react native's component's lifecycle?

Comment: @Codesingh I tried to use ComponentDidMount() and ComponentWillUnmount(), however ComponentWillUnmount() not triggered when I switch tab or push the next screen in the navigation stack.

Comment: How come this be possible?

Comment: please share the code.

Comment: componentDidMount() {
  NativeModules.MyModule.startSensors();
}
componentWillUnmount() {
  NativeModules.MyModule.stopSensors();
}

Comment: It is not being called since it actually is not unmounted. It remains in the nav stack so you can see it on the swipe back w/o having re-rendering it.

Comment: for sensor are you using third party or native code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137788/discussion-between-codesingh-and-vitalii-kalinin).

Comment: Hey, Is there any solution for this?